# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource (int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I'm working with collapsing parallax, inside the coordinate layout I have an element with id:imageViewTest that is in this file: activity_company_detail.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        ...
        >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        .../>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_company_detail"/>
```

In fragment class I try to call this element R.id.imageViewTest through the method view.findViewById (...), **this element is in the activity of this fragment**, it is necessary to change it programmatically its functionality.
CompanyDetailActivityFragment.java

```
private View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_company_detail, container, false);
ImageView  imageViewPrueba = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);
imageViewPrueba.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_logo_promo);
...
}
```

When trying to use this element I get the following error:
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource (int)' on a null object reference`

Try with getActivity.findViewById () but I'm still in the problem

Sorry for my English.

Thanks for the help @Kiryl-Tkach.

**Resolved**:

In the activity: CompanyDetailActivity.java

```
public void setImageDrawable(){
    ImageView  imageViewPrueba = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPrueba);
    imageViewPrueba.setImageDrawable(...));
}
```

In the fragment: CompanyDetailActivityFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(){
...
((CompanyDetailActivity)getActivity()).setImageDrawable();
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this because it is in not your fragments layout. Look at your method: `view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPrueba);`. You are looking it in your **view** object, which has layout `@layout/content_company_detail`, and it doesn't know anything about its activity. All you need to do is to create method in your activity setImageResource and call it from your fragment. Just remember that your fragment only should operate its own views, and the best practise to operate with other views is to call methods of other activities and fragments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am testing it and I have the doubt as I call the method of my activity from the fragment.  Activity:    public void setImageResource(int i ){
        ImageView  imageViewPrueba = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPrueba);
        imageViewPrueba.setImageResource(i);
    }

Comment: @Fahed Hermoza It's better to keep imageView variable in your main activity: private ImageView imageView;. In activity onCreate method: imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewPrueba);, and create method public void setImageResource(int i ){ imageView.setImageResource(i); }